# Add/sum multiple values in array with same id

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

So lets say i have the following array.

```
     [{idProduct:1, unitCost:400},
     {idProduct:1, unitCost:160},
     {idProduct:1, unitCost:46}, 
     {idProduct:2, unitCost:200},
     {idProduct:2, unitCost:40}
```

I cant seem to find the way to add the unit cost of product 1 and then cut off to add the other units cost of product 2 and so on... I actually want to append it to a different row in google spreadsheet but I first want to calculate it.

I tried some for/if loops but i always end up with the total cost for all products, not just individual ones.

This for gives out the total cost for all ids. When I palce an if inside this for, Im not sure how to compare the two ids, plus Im supposed to set totalCost back to 0 if i want to reset the sum

```
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length ; a++) {
    totalCost= totalCost+ arr[a].unitCost;
  }
```

I tried an if with a break but that doesnt seem to work either, wanted to maybe try promises but Im not sure that would help. I also tried to set another for that compares the next ids to the one im currently in but that seemed to complicate things and the numbers i got were wrong.

I also tried

```
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length ; a++) {
    if(arr[a].idProduct === arr[a+1].idProduct){
    totalCost= totalCost+ arr[a].unitCost;
    }
  }
```

But of course on the last id it compares it to undefinded since a+1 is longer than the length of the array.

Im honestly burned out by this by now, and im pretty sure its a simple solution, but I really dont know what else to do

Comment: What's the expected output

Comment: totalCost = 606 => for id 1
totalCost = 240 => for id 2

not sure where to store them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarize the array and add the values into an object using the `idProduct` as the key. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
let arr = [{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":400},{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":160},{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":46},{"idProduct":2,"unitCost":200},{"idProduct":2,"unitCost":40}]

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, {idProduct,unitCost}) => {
  c[idProduct] = c[idProduct] || {idProduct,unitCost: 0};
  c[idProduct].unitCost += unitCost;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log( result );
```

---

Or you can use the `idProduct` as the key like and the sum as the value like:

```js
let arr = [{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":400},{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":160},{"idProduct":1,"unitCost":46},{"idProduct":2,"unitCost":200},{"idProduct":2,"unitCost":40}]

let result = arr.reduce((c, {idProduct,unitCost}) => {
  c[idProduct] = c[idProduct] || 0;
  c[idProduct] += unitCost;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like below. This code adds `e.unitCost` to the object with the same `idProduct`

```js
var input = [{
    idProduct: 1,
    unitCost: 400
  },
  {
    idProduct: 1,
    unitCost: 160
  },
  {
    idProduct: 1,
    unitCost: 46
  },
  {
    idProduct: 2,
    unitCost: 200
  },
  {
    idProduct: 2,
    unitCost: 40
  }
];
var output = { };

input.forEach(e => output[e.idProduct] = (output[e.idProduct] || 0) + e.unitCost);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let pro;
let unitcost=[];
for (var a = 0; a < arr.length ; a++) {
    if(pro==arr[a].idProduct){
        unitcost[unitcost.length-1]+=arr[a].unitCost;
    }
    else{
        pro=arr[a].idProduct;
        unitcost.push(pro);
        unitcost.push(arr[a].unitCost);

    }   
}
console.log(unitcost);
```